# How to restrict access to web service using login password using iis

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, iis-7

I'm creating a web service (asmx) in c# and everything works fine except that everyone can connect to it. What I want to do is enable user-password protection (web service is hosted by iis 7.5) so client would use it like this:

```
using(var client = new SoapClient())
{
     client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";
     client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";

     var result = client.CallWebServiceMethod();
}
```

What should I do with iis to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc733010(WS.10).aspx or build your own custom httpmodule, I use this one: http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/, works perfect.

Comment: What kind of authentication is provided in my example?

Comment: If you go the httpmodule way you can use basic or digest authentication, which I would use. The client credentials from the soapclient use, I think, soap based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

This is a useful link 
[Web Services Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649362.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to disable Anonymous Acces to your web site and then create a windows account per client.